# URL rewrite - web.config error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am getting the following error when i run my .aspx page.

**Error Code0x8007000d
The configuration section 'rewrite' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration**

I have a simple v.aspx page which has the following code:

Response.Write(Request("q"))

My hosting server as IIS 7 installed with URL rewrite feature enabled (that's what they claim)

My web.config file has the following lines under :

Note: The  node has blue squiggly lines under it

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="v.aspx?q={R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I have searched stackoverflow but did not find a solution.

May be someone found a solution.

TIA

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make sure your `<rewrite>` is enclosed in the `<system.webServer></system.webServer>` section.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
          <rules>
             <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
             <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="v.aspx?q={R:1}" />
             </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: <rewrite> is enclosed in the <system.webServer></system.webServer> section.

Answer (score 19):

Install the URL Rewrite module http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite and that should be sorted. It fixed my problem

Comment: Worked for me too, but I used web platform installer to add it.

Comment: The download URL has been removed, you may download from here:https://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7435

Answer (score 3):

The rewrite section in system.webServer is supported in IIS7, but not IIS6. The error is likely caused by deploying this site to a server that's only running IIS6.

Comment: Encountered this problem as well for IIS8. Doing the install fixed it.